# Plotting lat/lon points and/or colormaps on local terrain map

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, openstreetmap

I am handling marine vessel positions, in lat/lon according to WGS84, from a gps as well as data from a magnetic anomaly chart, e.g. https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/emag2.html.

I would like to take the data from the magnetic anomaly chart and plot it as a colorbar over a basemap of a small region. Plan for the future is to integrate GPS position measurements of a vessel sailing as well.

The region I am considering is given by

```py
# Select frame upper and lower bounds
LAT = [54.8264, 55.1263]
LON = [9.8156, 10.6739]
```

which can be seen in https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=13/55.0628/10.2463.

A rough visualization of what I am trying to create would be an overlay of the colormap here
[image: image taken from https://noaa.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=6717e58b755b41298dc623d8fdc967dc]
onto the map from https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=13/55.0628/10.2463 along with some lat/lon coordinate points, to be added later.

As far as I can see the set of python libraries for plotting some kind of openstreetmap is quite expansive, do you have any recommendations for what would fit my purposes?

**Note:** I had considered matplotlib's `basemap` but apparently this is deprecated now, and the replacement, cartopy, doensn't seem to have the same "openstreetmap background" functionality that I was expecting.

**Edit:** I've made a contour plot of the magnetic data where the x and y-axes are longitude and latitude. I want to insert a map of the region in the background.

[image: magnetic contours]

Answer (score 0):

its a bit late, but from what I see [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) can definitely do the job now :-D )

Since you mention marine vessel positions... it also features [GEBC](https://www.gebco.net/) bathymetry maps to use as basemap!

```py
import numpy as np
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(*np.linspace([-45, -20], [45, 20], 1000).T)
data = np.sin(lon/5)**2 + np.cos(lat/5)
data[((0.5 < data) & (data < .8)) | (0 > data)] = None
#-----------------------------------------------------------------

from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps(Maps.CRS.GOOGLE_MERCATOR, layer="all")
m.add_wms.GEBCO.add_layer.GEBCO_LATEST()
m.add_wms.OpenStreetMap.add_layer.stamen_toner_labels(transparent=True)
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()

m2 = m.new_layer()
m2.set_data(data, lon, lat, crs=4326)
m2.set_shape.raster()
m2.set_classify_specs("EqualInterval", k=10)
m2.plot_map(cmap="turbo", alpha=.5, antialiased=True)

# add a colorbar
cb = m2.add_colorbar(histogram_size=999)
# remove transparency from the colorbar histogram
_ = [i.set_alpha(1) for i in m2.figure.ax_cb_plot.patches]
```

[image]